# issue when outputting an http:// address in a sub-array with json and php

Tags: php, json

Im trying to achieve an output like this

```
{"status":"ok","0":{"id":"11","title":"digg","url":"http://www.digg.com"}}
```

but instead i am getting this

```
{"status":"ok","0":{"id":"11","title":"digg","url":"http:\/\/www.digg.com"}}
```

this is the php code im using to generate the json

```
$links = array('id'=>'11','title'=>'digg','url'=>"http://www.digg.com");
$msg = array('status'=>'ok',$links);
echo json_encode($msg);
```

any idea what is causing this?

**UPDATE**
i should have been more clear
if you notice the actual url, its inserting "\" before the "/" in the output. Is this supposed to happen, or is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Why does it matter? At least if you leave it like that you ensure there won't be any problems when it's decoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both equivalent valid JSON, so it shouldn't matter.  The JSON strings:

```
"http://www.digg.com"
```

and

```
"http:\/\/www.digg.com"
```

both decode to:

```
"http://www.digg.com"
```

This is a separate issue, but I would prefer:

```
$links = array(array('id'=>'11','title'=>'digg','url'=>"http://www.digg.com"));
$msg = array('status'=>'ok', 'links'=>$links);
echo json_encode($msg);

{"status":"ok","links":[{"id":"11","title":"digg","url":"http:\/\/www.digg.com"}]}
```

This makes more sense to me than having a "0" key, and it extend well if you add more sites:

```
$links = array(array('id'=>'11','title'=>'digg','url'=>"http://www.digg.com"),
               array('id'=>'12','title'=>'reddit','url'=>"http://www.reddit.com"));
$msg = array('status'=>'ok', 'links'=>$links);
echo json_encode($msg);

{"status":"ok","links":[{"id":"11","title":"digg","url":"http:\/\/www.digg.com"},
{"id":"12","title":"reddit","url":"http:\/\/www.reddit.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The [JSON specs](http://json.org/).